# python print out csv data based on given date

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a python program that will print out from CSV. Code will ask the user to enter start date and end date, according to this range program return the temperature.

Here are the code which ask the user to enter start date and end date 
(
    import csv
    import datetime
    import time
    from datetime import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta

```
with open('preiction_system.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)


ask=input("Enter start  Date\n")

fromDate = time.strptime(ask, "%Y-%m-%d")
start = time.strptime(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),"%Y-%m-%d")


ask=input("Enter End Date\n")

fromDate = time.strptime(ask, "%Y-%m-%d")
end = time.strptime(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

It return the row from csv according to user input dates.

For example start date is 2019-12-01, end date is 2019-12-05

desire output:

```
Date          maxtempC  mintempC    tempC
2019/12/01  29.80    25.35          29.80
2019/12/02  29.78    25.34          29.78
2019/12/03  30.61    24.53          30.61
2019/12/04  32.08    24.75          32.08
2019/12/05  30.42    24.74          30.42
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error message

Comment: you have tag `pandas` but you don't use `pandas` in code. Remove tag. Or use `pandas` instead of `csv` module - probably it will be easier to resolve problem.

Comment: what did you try? I don't see any `if/else` to filter rows. You can compare even strings `if "2019/12/01" < "2019/12/02":`

Comment: ok i will try..

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` it can be

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('preiction_system.csv')

#start = input("Enter start  Date\n")
#end = input("Enter end  Date\n")

start = "2019/12/02"
end = "2019/12/04"

result = df[ (df['Date'] >= start ) & (df['Date'] <= end) ]

print(result)

result.to_csv('output.csv')
```

With `csv` it can be longer

```
import csv

# ask before `for` loop
#start = input("Enter start  Date\n")
#end = input("Enter end  Date\n")

start = "2019/12/02"
end = "2019/12/04"

result = []

with open('preiction_system.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(file_object)

    header = next(reader) # get header
    print(header)
    result.append(result)

    for row in reader:
        if start<= row[0] <= end:
            print(row)
            result.append(row)

# TODO: write result in file
```